# Error Executing transformation

Tags: java, analytics, pentaho, etl

I'm currently trying to export, transform and load some data to the database to do some analytics later on. However, upon running the application, it gives me an error!

Below is the code:

```
import org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment;
import org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException;
import org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans;
import org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta;

public class HelloWorldTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            KettleEnvironment.init();
            TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta("try.ktr");
            Trans trans = new Trans( metaData );
            trans.execute( null );
            trans.waitUntilFinished();
            if ( trans.getErrors() > 0 ) {
                System.out.print( "Error Executing transformation" );
            }
        } catch( KettleException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And below are the error:

```
Jun 07, 2016 10:35:16 PM org.apache.commons.vfs2.VfsLog info
INFO: Using "C:\Users\Gian\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
2016/06/07 22:35:17 - TRIAL - Dispatching started for transformation [TRIAL]
2016/06/07 22:35:17 - Table output.0 - Connected to database [HOY] (commit=1000)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/WorkbookSettings
child index = 0, logging object :       org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingObject@54a5733f parent=1645b834-7fb3-4c86-ab3d-a607681ab69c
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - TRIAL - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - TRIAL - Transformation is killing the other steps!
Error Executing transformation  at    org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.jxl.XLSWorkbook.<init>(XLSWorkbook.java:47)
at       org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.WorkbookFactory.getWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:39)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.getRowFromWorkbooks(ExcelInput.java:552)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.processRow(ExcelInput.java:430)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jxl.WorkbookSettings
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/WorkbookSettings
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.jxl.XLSWorkbook.<init>(XLSWorkbook.java:47)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.WorkbookFactory.getWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:39)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.getRowFromWorkbooks(ExcelInput.java:552)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.processRow(ExcelInput.java:430)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jxl.WorkbookSettings
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     ... 6 more
2016/06/07 22:35:24 - TRIAL - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Errors detected!`
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jxl.WorkbookSettings thats what you should be looking for

Answer (score 0):

This has already been solved! You just have to download jxl.jar and include that in the lib folder :)